# Trying to do interaction between 2 contracts. But compilation failure showing should be declared Abstract

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment

WinCon.sol
[image]

EnemyCon.sol

[image]

To create interaction, I am creating interface for EnemyCon in WinCon.sol, but Remix is throwing compilation error stating "EnemyCon should be marked abstract". I tried changing keyword Contract to Interface, but then then further it is not calling the function from other code. Please help, let me know what am I missing ?

Comment: Which solidity version are you using? Some version started to require unimplemented methods to be marked as abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Change `contract EnemyCon` to `interface EnemyCon`.

Also all methods inside interface has to be declared as `external`, so for method `setNum` remove the `public` keyword and add `external`.